# SQL Server authentication or Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, active-directory, icons, server

I am new to SQL Server management and I have a question about some of the icons used.

I know about the differences in authentication methods for SQL (Server vs AD). What I am not sure about is how to quickly determine which users authenticate via AD and which do not. I have a list of a few dozen login and I would like to easily spot the ones that use Server authentication.

My best guess is that (see the image below):

1. deactivated
2. AD authentication
3. Server authentication

[image]

Could you please confirm whether I am right or correct me?

Thanks

Comment: All windows user added a login to SQL Server will always use windows authentication. All logins created in SQL Server will always use SQL Server authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, logins that use Windows Authentication will start with

- An Active Directory domain name + backslash, for AD logins
- A machine name + backslash, for local logins

So in your list the only login using SQL Server Authentication is "sa" (system administrator login), in a addition to the special ##-logins, which are deactivated.